# Javascript string parameter in function

Tags: javascript

I'm working with google maps api and I want the label of a marker have a link that execute a warning.

```
var str = "hi";
var mp_position = createGoogleMapsLocation(data[i].location);
var text = "<p>Edit: <a href=# onClick='edit("+str+")'>Click here</a></p>";
addMeetingMarker(mp_position, text);
```

The addMeetingMarker function works, but edit function not. The code is:

```
function edit(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

If you set an integer in the argument of the edit function it works, but passing the variable str does not work. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need more double quotes to surround your value string - so:

```
var text = "<p>Edit: <a href=# onClick='edit("+str+")'>Click here</a></p>";
```

becomes

```
var text = "<p>Edit: <a href=# onClick='edit(\""+str+"\")'>Click here</a></p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
edit("+str+")
```

will result in the javascript code

```
edit(hi)
```

Where `hi` is an unknown variable.  Depending on what you want the `edit` function to do, either add a quote: `edit\""+str+"\")`, or remove the plusses: `edit(str)`.  In the last case, the edit function will receive the `str` variable, in the first case, it will receive the "hi" literal.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the double quotes necessary to make `str` a quoted string.